# How many speakers could I hook up to an RPi, and what additional hardware would I need?

Tags: audio, audio-playback

I know there are addon/expansion boards for the Rpi, but excluding these, how many separate speakers/channels could I reasonably output to?

I do not need audiophile-level sound quality, I don't even really need entertainment-level sound quality. I would like to be able to do alarm/siren tones, and perhaps a pager-level sound quality (a voice speaking a warning of some sort).

I expect to need an amp of some sort for each channel, and for anything more than two channels I think this means HDMI (this is fine, I'm not going to do video output). Are there amps that do HDMI-in?

Comment: Your question is very broad and too vaguely defined o elicit many answers. What type of speakers, loudspeakers, piezo's woofers etc.? What size speakers? What electrical characteristics do the speakers have? What does entertainment level sound and pager level sound mean? by channels do you mean individual speakers or a combination of speakers?

Comment: Some cheap speaker off of ebay or Amazon, whichever wouldn't break the bank. A speakers a speaker, and asking about woofers is silly... I already said this wasn't for entertainment. By channels, I mean "individual speakers" which is as I understand it, the meaning of the term. Thanks for downvoting though, appreciate that.

Comment: You are making a lot of assumptions. A speaker is most definitely not guaranteed to be like every other speaker. If you want to split into treble, midrange and bass ranges, for example, you're going to possibly be looking at an altogether different set of solutions. If you want "alarm/siren tones", a piezo solution might be a viable answer (you didn't provide sufficient detail to know) but will in turn require a different solution depending on the driving voltages. You're taking offense at people trying to help you out where you've provided only the vaguest of detail.

Answer (score 2):

One way to go is using multiple USB sound cards, though reports about the number of supported sound cards differ.

These posts claim that `alsa` supports up to 32 devices without much fiddling:

- [Need more than 32 USB sound cards on my system](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14201551/3984613)
- [Why does Linux have a maximum number of sound cards?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/255542/82256)

Whereas this [discussion](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=38&t=35243) at the Raspberry Pi forum reports a number of 8 devices working:

> So I've got 12 USB Audio devices that I need to use for audio out for an art project. The problem is that the Pi will only recognize 8 total devices at any one time (i've got 10 plugged in right now).

So while the discussion over there ended without a conclusion one would guess that `alsa` is able to detect up to 8 devices on the Pi.

USB 2.0 with a maximum signaling rate of 480 Mbit/s is said to provide an effective throughput of about 35 MB/s ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB)). Assume a 5.1 (= 6 channel) sound card at 44.1 kHz and 16 bit results in roughly 500 kB/s which would put even 8 devices well within the bandwidth limitations of USB. Doesn't look this bad so far. Final question is now whether the Pi's tiny, tiny core can handle the load - which I leave as an exercise for the reader.

Audio hats for the Pi are likely not a good solution as they cannot be stacked (to my knowledge).

Answer (score 2):

Look for an "audio distribution amplifier". A quick search finds several that support 8 outputs off a single input. I found used 10 output units on eBay. As you note, each output will, in turn, require an amp to drive the speakers. If you're not after quality, you can probably stack them, although there's sure to be a limit. They key point is that the input (your RPi in this case) is not the limiting factor.

If you just want noisemakers, I'd look into controlling several independent units centrally. That way, theoretically, your only constraint is your budget. Use a microcontroller or RPi at each set of speakers, then control them via MQTT over wireless. Each could play back mp3 or other audio, or if you just want noise, trigger horns, bells or whatever you want.

If this isn't what you want, you're going to have to do a better job explaining what you are after.

Comment: I'd like to get as many channels/speakers out of a single RPi as I reasonably can. I don't want to use the gpio header, I've got that reserved for something else. 2 channels out of the stereo out is insufficient. I don't know that the RPi is what I want, but other solutions are going to be either too expensive, or too much of a pain in the ass (SIP speakers, for instance).

Comment: Then I'd go with multiple, independent devices, each of which is a RPi or microcontroller triggered off a central RPi. How closely do the sounds need to be synchronized?