# How do I send a mono-wav file to a specific channel out of my USB audio interface from a RPi 4?

Tags: audio-playback, usb-audio

My USB audio interface is a Behringer UMC-1820. I'm working on a 8 channel sound installation where I'm sending mono audio to a specific output of the AI. I've seen a post [How to feed 8 speakers 8 different signals using a Raspberry Pi?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/74306/how-to-feed-8-speakers-8-different-signals-using-a-raspberry-pi) here where you write to an eight channel audio file using `ffmpeg` and then play this multichannel audio file.

Due to memory constraints (the amount of mono-files) I would really like to target this mono file to **one direct output** of the AI. I was thinking to use [Supercollider](https://supercollider.github.io/) to first read a buffer, then send it to the relevant out. However I would like to do this from the terminal.